# Silverlight - read and write to XML-file with DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to bind xml-data to a Silverlight data-grid. At the moment I have been "playing" with the DevExpress tools for Silverlight. I don't know how different it is using these tools compared to the standard way, since I'm fairly new to Silverlight.

On their website I've found the following example to retrieve data from one XML-file.

**Now I want to be able to save modifications I made within the datagrid to this xml-file and also add and delete rows that will also affect the XML-file.**

```
namespace XMLReadWrite {
public partial class MainPage : UserControl {

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        grid.ItemsSource = GetData();
    }
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Contacts.xml", LoadOptions.None);

    ObservableCollection<Contact> GetData() {



        var items = from item in doc.Descendants("Contacts")
                    select new Contact() {
                        FirstName = item.Element("FirstName").Value,
                        LastName = item.Element("LastName").Value,
                        Company = item.Element("Company").Value,
                        City = item.Element("City").Value
                        //ID = int.Parse(item.Element("ID").Value)
                    };

        ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        foreach (Contact contact in items) {
            contacts.Add(contact);
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    private void SaveToXML()
    { }


    private void Save_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveToXML();
    }        
}

public class Contact {
    public int ID {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string FirstName {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string LastName {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Company {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string City
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
}
```

This is probably an easy task but I'm stuck since I don't have a clue what needs to be done here.
Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whats the question?  How to save the items back to xml?

Answer (score 0):

You dont mention how you are getting your xml file, so there are few options, one save it to local storage and load it from local storage, [heres](http://www.insidercoding.com/post/2008/08/08/Tutorial-Reading-and-Writing-Files-in-Silverlight.aspx) a article on the subject, two retrieve it from the server and save it to the server, [heres](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/loading_xml_sl2_pg1.htm) an article on the subject or three some combo of either. As far as working with XML, it looks like you are using linq to xml to read the data into a collection of Contacts, I recommend reading and going through these links

1. [Linq to Xml Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688087.aspx)
2. [Using LINQ to XML to Add Data to XML File in C#](http://www.programminghelp.com/programming/dotnet/using-linq-to-xml-to-add-data-to-xml-file-in-c/)
3. [Creating and Saving XML tree using LINQ to XML](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/creatingsavingxmltreelinq07292009084107AM/creatingsavingxmltreelinq.aspx)

The thing about Linq to Xml is that its not specific to silverlight, these skills also transfer well to server programming.

Now the task of adding and removing items from the datagrid, well depending on how you deside to architect your solution, theres MVVM or straightforward code-behind, id recommend spending the time to get to know MVVM, its a design pattern that fits very well in the world of silverlight, it will save you hair in the long run. [Heres](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/RIADataGrid.aspx) a article on this problem domain using MVVM.

**EDIT**

```
  grid.ItemsSource as  ObservableCollection<Contact>();
```

will give you back the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the info and link material! Unfortunately I can't figure out how I use the modified grid cells to update the Xml-file as well.

Comment: your collection should automatically have the changes applied to each contact that was modified, check that this is the case if so just serialize the collection back to the file using the methods described in the links.